# Native JSON support for BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any plan for Google BigQuery to implement native JSON support?

I am considering migrating hive data (~20T) to Google BigQuery,
but the table definitions in Hive contains map type which is not supported in BigQuery.

for example, the HiveQL below:

```
select gid, payload['src'] from data_repository;
```

although, it can be worked around by using regular expression.

Comment: Just a heads up, we've started to support for JSON data ingestion, and as an export format (see: googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/10/got-big-json-bigquery-expands-data.html)

Comment: A decade later, native JSON support is finally available in BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data

Answer (score 3):

As of 1 Oct 2012, BigQuery supports newline separated JSON for import and export.

Blog post: http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/10/got-big-json-bigquery-expands-data.html

Documentation on data formats: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#dataformats

Comment: But as of today, there are still basic JSON path operations missing like `[*]`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719880/bigquery-jsonpath-values-of-json-array

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to coerce all of your types into csv before importing, and if you have complex fields, decompose them via a regular expression in the query (as you suggested).

That said, we are actively investigating support for new input formats, and are interested in feedback as to what formats would be the most useful. There is support in the underlying query engine ([Dremel](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CI0BEBYwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Fpubs%2Farchive%2F36632.pdf&ei=2i-tT-qBEKHliALVwpHqBg&usg=AFQjCNEzKp2CK_JKM_U2XCfDn9qjf0MKMA&sig2=t2SHkiy-WDftsQlcna_T6g)) for types similar to the hive map type, but BigQuery, however, does not currently expose a mechanism for ingesting nested records.