# How can I apply aggregate functions to data extracted from JSON in Google BigQuery?

Tags: sql, json, aggregate-functions, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I am extracting JSON data out of a [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) column using `JSON_EXTRACT`. Now I want to extract lists of values and run aggregate functions (like `AVG`) against them. Testing the JsonPath expression `.objects[*].v` succeeds on http://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/. But the query:

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.id") as id,
  AVG(JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.objects[*].v")) as average_value
FROM [tablename]
```

throws a **JsonPath parse error** on BigQuery. **Is this possible on BigQuery?** Or do I need to preprocess my data in order to run aggregate functions against data inside of my JSON?

My data looks similar to this:

```
# Record 1
{
  "id": "abc",
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "v": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "v": 3
    }
  ]
}
# Record 2
{
  "id": "def",
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "v": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "v": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

This is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548856/native-json-support-for-bigquery).

**Update:** The problem can be simplified by running two queries. First, run `JSON_EXTRACT` and save the results into a view. Secondly, run the aggregate function against this view. But even then I need to correct the JsonPath expression `$.objects[*].v` to prevent the `JSONPath parse error`.

Comment: Anything from jsonpath that can return a list of things (eg: [*], [:2], ...) doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Asking specifically about the `*`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719880/bigquery-jsonpath-values-of-json-array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leverage SPLIT() to pivot repeatable fields into separate rows. Also might be easier/cleaner to put this into a subquery and put AVG outside:

```
SELECT id, AVG(v) as average 
FROM (
SELECT 
    JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.id") as id, 
    INTEGER( 
      REGEXP_EXTRACT(
        SPLIT(
          JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, "$.objects")
          ,"},{"
          )
        ,r'\"v\"\:([^,]+),')) as v FROM [mytable] 
)
GROUP BY id;
```