# How to get all values of an attribute of json array with jsonpath bigquery in bigquery? Asterisk operator not supported.

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get all the values of a certain attribute from a json array.
Considering the following json, I'm trying to get all the types e.g. iPhone,home

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName" : "doe",
 "age"      : 26,
 "address"  :
 {
     "streetAddress": "naist street",
     "city"         : "Nara",
     "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
 },
 "phoneNumbers":
 [
     {
       "type"  : "iPhone",
       "number": "0123-4567-8888"
     },
     {
       "type"  : "home",
       "number": "0123-4567-8910"
     }
 ]
}
```

I am using `$.phoneNumbers[*].type` which seems to work fine on [online parsers](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/?)
but when I'm using it in big query:

```
select json_extract(my_column,'$.phoneNumbers[*].type')
from my_table
```

I get:

```
JSONPath parse error at: [*].type
```

Comment: That syntax looks correct, but for some reason doesn't work, maybe @JordanTigani can know why, but look for a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616094/how-can-i-apply-aggregate-functions-to-data-extracted-from-json-in-google-bigque

Answer (score 7):

You can write a Javascript UDF to do the extraction:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[1,2,3]', '$[*]') parsed 
Error: Unsupported operator in JSONPath: *
```

UDF alternative:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseJson(libs STRING)
    RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
      try {
        return JSON.parse(libs);
      } catch (e) {
        return [];
      }
    """;
SELECT parseJson('[1,2,3]') parsed
```

More complex example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseJson(libs STRING)
    RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y INT64, z INT64>>
    LANGUAGE js AS """
      try {
        return JSON.parse(libs);
      } catch (e) {
        return [];
      }
    """;
SELECT parseJson(JSON_EXTRACT('{"a":[{"x":1},{"y":2},{"z":3}]}', '$.a')) parsed
```

(inspired by: https://discuss.httparchive.org/t/javascript-library-detection/955)

Answer (score 5):

json_extract cannot return REPEATED field, it can only do one match - hence no support for *

Comment: Consider explaining that on the docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions What is a REPEATED field: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020714/what-does-repeated-field-in-google-bigquery-mean

Answer (score 2):

Yet another interesting (*I hope*) solution for BigQuery Standard SQL
Can be easily adjusted to whatever specific needs are

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION parseJson(data STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<parent STRING, item STRING, key STRING, value STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  x = JSON.parse(data); z = []; processKey(x, '');
  function processKey(node, parent) {
    if (parent !== '') {parent += '.'};
    Object.keys(node).map(function(key) {
      value = node[key].toString();
      if (!value.startsWith('[object Object]')) {
        var q = {}; var arr = parent.split('.');
        q.parent = arr[0]; q.item = arr[1];
        q.key = key; q.value = value;
        z.push(q);
      } else {
        processKey(node[key], parent + key);
      };
    });    
  }; return z;
""";
WITH t AS (    
  SELECT """ {
   "firstName": "John",
   "lastName" : "doe",
   "age"      : 26,
   "address"  :  {
       "streetAddress": "naist street", "city" : "Nara", "postalCode" : "630-0192" },
   "phoneNumbers": [
      { "type"  : "iPhone", "number": "0123-4567-8888"},
      { "type"  : "home",   "number": "0123-4567-8910"},
      { "type"  : "work",   "number": "0123-4567-7777"}]
  } """ AS info
)
SELECT parent, item, key, value FROM t, UNNEST(parseJson(info))
WHERE parent = 'phoneNumbers' AND key = 'type'
```