# SQL Query validation failure on GCP BigQuery with github_repos dataset

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, github-api

I would like to get a list all unique repositories on GutHub by using the following command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT repo_name FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
```

However I get the following error:

> Column repo_name of type ARRAY cannot be used in SELECT DISTINCT at [1:17]

In the schema it says repo_name is of type STRING, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another user posted, in the schema of the `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` table you can see that the `repo_name` field is defined as a [STRING REPEATED](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) which means that each entry of `repo_name` is an array constituted by string-type elements. You can see this with the following query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT repo_name 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` 
LIMIT 100;
```

In order to find the distinct repo names you can employ the [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) operator to expand each one of the `repo_name` elements. The following query performs a CROSS JOIN that adds a new field `repo_name_single` to the table constituted by the individual repository names. This way, the `DISTINCT` function can be employed.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT(repo_name_unnest) 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(repo_name) AS repo_name_unnest;
```

Answer (score 2):

repo_name is defined as a "string" with mode "repeated" in the table schema which roughly means an ARRAY of STRING in BigQuery.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated

[What does REPEATED field in Google Bigquery mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020714/what-does-repeated-field-in-google-bigquery-mean)

[image]

Comment: I see, this is very helpful to know, thanks! Now I have to figure out how to craft my query for an array type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

```
SELECT 
    commit
   , repo_name 
FROM 
   `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`, 
    UNNEST(repo_name) as repo_name 
WHERE 
    commit = 'c87298e36356ac19519a93dee3dfac8ebffe45e8'
```

Which will give a result like below

```
Row |  commit                                  | repo_name
===================================================================
1   | c87298e36356ac19519a93dee3dfac8ebffe45e8 | noondaysun/sakai
2   | c87298e36356ac19519a93dee3dfac8ebffe45e8 | OpenCollabZA/sakai
```

Comment: I actually want to run a query that will give me a list of all the unique repos on GitHub from all the commits that are stored on big query. If I am not wrong your query returns all repos with a particular commit hash.

Comment: You can remove the where condition and your select statement to `SELECT distinct (repo_name)` . I added the where condition to not run the entire query. If this was helpful do accept the answer.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT
   (repo_name) 
FROM 
   bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits', 
    UNNEST(repo_name) as repo_name`
I formatted the query to look like this?

Comment: Should work fine. If this answer was useful please do accept the answer