# Descend into JSON array in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way to descend into a Json array in BigQuery, such as with the following example?

**JSonPath**

```
$.phoneNumbers[*].type
```

**Inputs**

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Results**

```
[
  "iPhone",
  "home"
]
```

[image]

The best I think I can do is either (1) go to a specify index in the array or (2) stop at the array itself and not descend further. Here is an example query:

```
with tbl as (select json '''{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}''' as j)
select j.phoneNumbers[0].number from tbl
```

[image: 2]

Is there any way to go beyond this in a json value?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719880/how-to-get-all-values-of-an-attribute-of-json-array-with-jsonpath-bigquery-in-bi

Comment: Since `[*]` is not supported, everytime you see an array when you descend down the json path, you should stop to unnest it and descend down again one by one from each element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine and use :

- JSON_QUERY_ARRAY
- UNNEST
- JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR

.

```
with tbl as (select json '''{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}''' as j)


select json_extract_scalar(e,'$.type')  as types from tbl, unnest(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(j,'$.phoneNumbers')) e
```

this returns:

[image]

You may further combine this as:

```
select JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(j,'$.firstName') as firstname, 
       array_agg(json_extract_scalar(e,'$.type')) as types from tbl, unnest(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(j,'$.phoneNumbers')) e
group by 1
```

to produce per user

[image]